# Shell Script to replace certains strings on certain conditions

Tags: shell-script

I have to write a shell script which read my whole xml file and search that if certain conditions are getting fulfilled then it remove some particular lines.

Suppose my xml is in this form

```
<midget action="D">
    <lists operator="AND">
        <list name="productCode" value="XW143215" actionoperator="in"
            oldoperator="in" type="string" />
        <list name="%%PromotionProductInstanceId%%" value="z" product="S0000001.S0145868"
            actionoperator="in" operator="=" oldoperator="in" type="string" />
        <list name="Type" value="ALL" product="PQRAccess" type="string" />
        <lists id="Prim" />
    </lists>

</midget>

<midget action="Y">
    <lists operator="AND">
        <list name="productCode" value="XW143215" actionoperator="in"
            oldoperator="in" type="string" />
        <list name="Y" value="z" product="S0000001.S0145868"
            actionoperator="in" operator="=" oldoperator="in" type="string" />
        <list name="Type" value="ALL" product="PQRAccess" type="string" />
        <lists id="Trim" />
    </lists>

</midget>

<midget action="D">
    <lists operator="AND">
        <list name="productCode" value="XW143215" actionoperator="in"
            oldoperator="in" type="string" />
        <list name="%%PromotionProductInstanceId%%" value="z" product="S0000001.S0145868"
            actionoperator="in" operator="=" oldoperator="in" type="string" />
        <list name="Type" value="ALL" product="PQRAccess" type="string" />
        <lists id="Trim" />
    </lists>

</midget>
```

Now my shell script will search for these conditions:

- Starting element should be `<midget`
- on which action="D"
- then in list element name="%%PromotionProductInstanceId%%"
- then in list element value="ALL"

Then script should remove both of these statements from midget element.

```
<list name="%%PromotionProductInstanceId%%" value="z" product="S0000001.S0145868"
            actionoperator="in" operator="=" oldoperator="in" type="string" />
<list name="Type" value="ALL" product="PQRAccess" type="string" />
```

I have tried sed but i am unable to figure out how to perform search based on above conditions. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: To manipulate XML, I strongly recommend using an XML tools such as [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/docs.php) rather than generic tools such as `sed`.

Comment: @StephenKitt, [obligatory link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/5419599).  ;)

Comment: @StephenKitt But what if I want to achieve this via shell. Isn't it possible.

Comment: @Wildcard Thanks man but it's a whole other requirement. I have written following code to match and extract those statements. cat $fullPathWithFilename|sed 's/<midget/\n/g'|grep "Trim"|grep 'value="ALL"'|sed 's/<list name="PromotionProductInstanceId".*<lists/<lists/g'|sed 's/^/<midget /g' >> $DIR/temp.xml

Comment: Also when you are down voting, at least have a courtesy to jot down the reason in comment section so that we don't repeat the mistakes in future.Thanks

Comment: See the link.  Any *particular* XML file may be successfully parsed by a sed script.  But there is NO sed script (and no regex at all, not even PCREs) that can successfully handle ALL validly formed XML.  So if you are doing this as a one-time change in a static file, use a good editor such as Vim and do it interactively.  And if you're writing code to handle dynamic XML modifications, **don't use regex.** Use an XML parser.

Comment: @Wildcard While what you write is practically true and rexexp are not suited to parse XML, you can theoretically write an `sed` script to parse all validly formed XML. It's just as complex that not even an `sed` enthusiast did ever do it (although they do [a lot of weird stuff](http://sed.sourceforge.net/)). So it's wrong that there is NO script, it's just not yet written. (-;

Comment: @Philippos, yes, you are technically correct.  *regex* is what can't parse XML.  Sed, being Turing complete, of course can.  It can also convert JSON into XML and vice versa; that doesn't mean it's sane to do so.  ;)

Answer (score 3):

With [XmlStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/):

```
xml ed -d '//midget[@action="D"]/*[
    descendant::list[@name="%%PromotionProductInstanceId%%"] and
    descendant::list[@value="ALL"]]/list[
    @name="%%PromotionProductInstanceId%%" or @value="ALL"]' <file.xml
```

In detail:

- starting element should be `<midget`: `//midget`
- on which `action="D"`: `[@action="D"]`
- then in list element `name="%%PromotionProductInstanceId%%"`: `descendant::list[@name="%%PromotionProductInstanceId%%"]`
- then in list element `value="ALL"`: `descendant::list[@value="ALL"]`
- then script should remove both of these statements from midget element: `list[@name="%%PromotionProductInstanceId%%" or @value="ALL"]`